# how to set up rolling on a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, moving-average

I created a moving average using rolling on a dataframe using the following source code

```
    ma = produksi.price.rolling(window=3).mean()
    hasil = hasil.append(ma)
    mape= abs((produksi.price-ma)/produksi.price)
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

but the results of the moving average are like this, the calculation is correct, but the position is not as expected

I want the result like this
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

to calculate the error value in the prediction of the fourth data
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8FBf.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CalcT.png

Comment: Please provide your data in the text of your question, not as an image or link. See [How to make good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you add the `closed='left'` parameter to rolling method you will get the desired outcome.

[pandas rolling documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html)

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'price': [3290, 3380, 3380, 3360, 3340, 3290, 3300]})
df['mean'] = df['price'].rolling(window=3, closed='left').mean()
```

Output

```
print(df)
   price         mean
0   3290          NaN
1   3380          NaN
2   3380          NaN
3   3360  3350.000000
4   3340  3373.333333
5   3290  3360.000000
6   3300  3330.000000
```